# anchor element hover only works on one slide of a bootstrap 4 carousel, but not on others

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="carousel-fade" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1500" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption embed-responsive-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="logo">
          <a class="myButton" href="#">SERVICES</a><a class="myButton" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1500" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption embed-responsive-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="logo">
          <a class="myButton" href="#">SERVICES</a><a class="myButton" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1500" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption embed-responsive-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="logo">
          <a class="myButton" href="#">SERVICES</a><a class="myButton" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-fade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-fade" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: -40px !important; }

.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 300px !important;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  padding-top: 20px !important; 
  vertical-align: center;
}

.carousel-caption > p {
  font-size: 0.7em; }

.carousel-caption > .myButton {
  color: #E8E8E8;
  z-index: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #E8E8E8;
  padding: 0 26px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 150px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background: none; 
}

.carousel-caption > .myButton:hover {
  color: #11190E;
  background: #E8E8E8; 
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-out .7s;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Heres also a codepen link, https://codepen.io/JamieBullock87/full/vRbybv/

Im using bootstrap 4, and have an image carousel which fades from slide to slide. I have a logo and two buttons as the carousel-captions which are displayed in front of the sliding images.
I've set :hover css animations on the buttons, but they only fire when on the last slide (3), when you hover over the buttons when the carousel is on slides 1+2 nothing happens, but works perfectly on the last slide.

I am at my wits end, since the code is exactly the same for each slide, can anyone help me with what i'm missing here please?

Cheers

J

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:block` from `.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item{}`

Here is the [fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmNXdN)

```css
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: -40px !important; }

.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 300px !important;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  padding-top: 20px !important; 
  vertical-align: center;
}

.carousel-caption > p {
  font-size: 0.7em; }

.carousel-caption > .myButton {
  color: #E8E8E8;
  z-index: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #E8E8E8;
  padding: 0 26px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 150px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background: none; 
}

.carousel-caption > .myButton:hover {
  color: #11190E;
  background: #E8E8E8; 
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-out .7s;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="container">
  <div id="carousel-fade" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1500" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption embed-responsive-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="logo">
          <a class="myButton" href="#">SERVICES</a><a class="myButton" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1500" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption embed-responsive-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="logo">
          <a class="myButton" href="#">SERVICES</a><a class="myButton" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1500" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption embed-responsive-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="logo">
          <a class="myButton" href="#">SERVICES</a><a class="myButton" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-fade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-fade" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works to get the hover effects going, but it stops the transition animation for moving from slide to slide. It's now an abrupt change rather than a smooth fade in/fade out effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: There must be a way to have the fade in and fade out transition as well as some simple button animations too?
It is as if there is an overlay that's blocking the buttons hover action from firing?
I've tried setting positions and z index's to no avail, setting the display:block to only be on the active slide, but that kills the smooth transition too. I can't be the first person who wanted to animate a button on a BS4 fadeIn/fadeOut carousel surely?

Comment: you can try on click event on arrows. and give fadeIn() function to carousel item.

Comment: like this:$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeIn();
});